# scale parameters to be between 0 and 1 for optimization

Tags: python, optimization, wrapper

I want to normalize the paramaters for the optimization, all the parameters   values should be scaled between [0,1].Just for demonstrating purposes here is an simple example:

```
from scipy import optimize
import numpy as np

def blabla(params): ### SOME FUNCTION WE WANT TO MINIMIZE
    x1,x2,x3=params #### PARAMETERS OF THE FUNCTION
    c=100+x1*9*x2-3*x3
    return(c)

def RMSE(params):####OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
    return ((np.sqrt((blabla(params)-100)**2))) ##100 it is the original value

guess=[1,2,3] ####INITIAL GUESS
res=optimize.minimize(RMSE, guess,method='Nelder-Mead', options={'xtol': 0.00001,'ftol':0.000001, 'disp': True}) ###NELDER-MEAD
```

How can I build a wraper around this function to have the params values scaled so that x1[0,1], x2[0,1],x3[0,1], the old parameters scale was x1[0,1],x2[0,3],x3[0,5].Should I rewrite the whole function or is there any more convinient way. Would appreciate any hint.

Comment: If you're not afraid to import another library you can try [Scikit learn's normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html#sklearn-preprocessing-normalize).

Comment: The problem is the params argument. I don't know how to modify the x1, x2,x3 from the params argument

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite sure what you mean. If you have a matrix of datapoints with columns x1, x2, x3, then you should be able to normalize.

Comment: the x1 x2 and x3 shoud be rescaled so that their values are between 0 and 1.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what normalization does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before scaling the parameters, you must know the **max(params)** and **min(params)**.
Then, you can scale the values between 0 to 1 as follows:

*Normalized[x1]*=**(x1-min(params)) / (max(params)-min(params))**

The below example code works fine:

```
test=[1,3,5] #test values
def norm(params = [], *args):
    new_list=[]
    print params
    for x in params:
        y=(float(x)-min(params))/(max(params)-min(params)) #normalize
        new_list.append(y)
    return new_list
output=norm(test)
print output
```

code that is to be added to your program:

```
def blabla(params): ### SOME FUNCTION WE WANT TO MINIMIZE
    x1,x2,x3=params #### PARAMETERS OF THE FUNCTION
    x1=(float(x1)-min(x1,x2,x3))/(max(x1,2,x3)-min(x1,x2,x3)) ## Similarly for x2 and x3
    c=100+x1*9*x2-3*x3
    return(c)
```

Comment: I know how this works but how exactly apply this on my example

Comment: After you assign values to x1,x2,x3( in 'blabla' of your code) just find the min and max values and apply the above logic.